# Github Workflow can't install python packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image every time when someone commits to the "main" branch. I want to install my packages from my `requirements.txt`. When I build the image local everything works fine, but when my pipeline in Github tries to build it I get the following error:

`Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/
COPY .. /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 8080
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The directory structure is:

[image: structure]

And the Github yaml:

```
name: Docker-Image CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./flask_web/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}/dbdashboard:latest
```

I really don't understand where the problem is. Installing the packages manually via `pip install Flask` in the Dockerfile works.

Comment: there should be some other(and more important) error logs.

Comment: It seems like he can't find the file: ```#11 [6/6] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
194
#11 1.371 ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt```

Comment: you can try some command such as `pwd` `ls -al` to determine the current working directory.

Comment: The working directory is ```/usr/src/app``` but even when I change the Dockerfile to ```pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt``` Github don't find the file. Local its working again. I think that the configuration of the pipeline is the problem...

Comment: what's output of `ls -l /usr/src/app`?

Comment: local its all the files from the screenshot I posted inside the ```flask_web``` folder. But I can't look into to container from the build pipeline in GitHub.

Comment: but you can look into container in the github action logs.

Comment: the build fails after installing the packages. So where I should look then?

Comment: add `ls -l /usr/src/app`, **before** `pip install`.

Comment: Okay so the structure in the pipeline was/is different. Basically I had to ```cd``` into the ```flask_web``` folder to install the dependencies like ```pip install -r flask_web/requirements.txt``` and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think they are the same, you misunderstood what's root path of a git repo.

Comment: Yes. The root path locally is direct the ```flask_web``` folder and the root path from the git repo is one folder above

Comment: git(or github) don't care your business logic. their current directory is where `.git` lies.